# Change the Font Color of the Last 3 Digits in a Number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with some of my code in Excel VBA.

I have an identification number that's always 7 digits long and is located in column B. I need to take the last 3 digits of the ID number and change the font color.

I've tried using the Right() function, but I can't figure out how to combine it with the Font.Color function.

```
Sub Test    

Dim i As Long
    
For i = 1 To 3
    RResult = Right(ActiveCell, 3)
    LResult = Left(ActiveCell, 4)
    ActiveCell = LResult + " " + RResult
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i
    
End Sub
```

I tried the above code to seperate the digits, but I can't change the font color of the RResult (Right Result) variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub Test    

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 3
    RResult = Right(ActiveCell, 3)
    LResult = Left(ActiveCell, 4)
    ActiveCell = LResult + " " + RResult
    ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=6, Length:=3).Font.Color = 255
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This method gives you a few more options:

You pass it the range reference and an optional character count and RGB colour.

```
Public Sub ColourLastThree(Target As Range, Optional CharCount As Long = 3, Optional RGBColour As Long = 255)

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Target
        If Len(rCell) >= CharCount Then
            rCell = "'" & rCell
            rCell.Characters(Start:=Len(rCell) - (CharCount - 1), Length:=CharCount).Font.Color = RGBColour
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

You can then call the procedure:

```
'Colour the last three characters in the ActiveCell to red.
Sub Test()
    ColourLastThree ActiveCell
End Sub

'Colour last four characters in Sheet1!A1 to red.
Sub Test1()
    ColourLastThree Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), 4
End Sub

'Colour last four characters in Sheet1!A1 to Green.
Sub Test2()
    ColourLastThree Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3"), 4, RGB(0, 255, 0) 'or can use 65535 as RGB.
End Sub

'Colour last three character in each cell on the ActiveSheet in A1:A4.
Sub Test3()
    ColourLastThree Range("A1:A4")
End Sub
```

**Edit:**  I've updated the code to cycle through each cell in the passed Target range (as shown in Test3 procedure).

Comment: *This method gives you a few more options:* ... indeed +:)